# Questions regarding Angular 2 files

Tags: angularjs

Could someone help a newbee. I just went through the Angular.io quickstart. 
I finally got the project to run but the following questions came up.

First:  These points  the quickstart guide stated that App.module.ts is the app entry point. That it consumes the component app.component.ts and that main.ts initializes the platform that your app runs in.  Also, there's index.html.

**So in plain English is this correct.**

App.module.ts (Is this like the main of the program)

app.component.ts (Is a module that app.module.ts consumes).

(main.ts) Initializes the nodejs platform (I am assuming that means gets the environment that Javascript run in ready on your pc.)

index.html (is the start web page)

Also, do you always start every app with Index.html as the main starting web page for Angular 2 apps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### App.module.ts (Is this like the main of the program)

*This is the module you use to bootstrap/setup your main module and declare app dependencies such as ngMaterial*

### app.component.ts (Is a module that app.module.ts consumes).

*This is the module you would use to create routes to link to other modules and be the base module*

### (main.ts) Initializes the nodejs platform (I am assuming that means gets the environment that Javascript run in ready on your pc.)

*This is the main entry module and here you can swap out the JiT (Just in Time) compiler for an AoT (Ahead of Time) compilation to make the app even more skinny*

### index.html (is the start web page)

*This is just the file which includes the correct js files, this could be called anything*

Hope that helps I am still learning myself so if anything is wrong please point them out so I can alter it and learn.